# MySQL with multiple database encodings in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, database, encoding

I have a database set up to use the `encoding UTF-8 multibyte-4`. This is configured in the `my.cnf` file:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

(...)

character-set-server            = utf8mb4
collation-server                = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I would like to add a 2nd database, let's call them `DB1` and `DB2`.

The problem: The application that uses this 2nd database `DB2` cannot work with the encoding I have configured in `my.cnf`. It's a 3rd party application, so I have no possibility to change something, all I can do is modify the databse setup.

If I comment the above lines in `my.cnf`, the 3rd party application works, I guess it's using plain `UTF-8 encoding`. But now the system using the 1st database `DB1` fails on encoding.

Is there a way to specify a default encoding in `my.cnf` for each database, separating `DB1` encoding from `DB2`? Searching the internet has not shown me any solution other than using a separate/2nd MySQL installation.

Using `MySQL version 5.6.x`

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to the application that connects to DB1, then you probably can change the encoding on per connection base. I.e. when the application connects to the database server, it changes the connection character set, so it should work the way it's supposed to.

I guess all applications should be developed with utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

1. Shoot that 3rd party software.
2. Have utf8 in my.cnf.  Perform `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` in that applications that need it and that you can get to.

Comment: that is so far the best solution i have tried, thanks! both applications do work if i set UTF8 in my.cnf. however, our own application running on `DB1` is now unable to store characters like emojis, and possibly other characters, i haven't done extensive testing in that area so far. still, better than installing and running MySQL twice.

Comment: Emojis and some Chinese characters need utf8mb4, not utf8.